# Validate value in text_area

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, syntax-highlighting

I have a text_area in my rails app where users can paste plain text or code. I really don't want to ask the user to choose text or code for me but want to make it like a WYSWYG text area

- Right now I use pre tag. This renders code comments ok but makes text comments look visually ugly.
- I can use a syntax highlighting gem, but this requires me to know that the pasted text is code.
- Q: Is there any inbuilt apis in rails/ruby to validate if the value in a text area  is code or text?

  ```
  <% if !comment.content.blank? %>    
                 <p> <pre> <%= simple_format comment.content  %></pre>  </p>
  <% end %>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instruct the user to wrap the code section around a specific keyword..for instance {code}
then in your template you can extract and decorate the the code section:

```
<p> <pre><%= comment.content.scan(/{code}(.*?){code}/m)  %></pre></p>
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, for your suggestion. I think I will go with Redcarpet gem. It seems to handle URLs and code.